# org-mode export with utf8x instead of utf8

Tags: emacs

All the fancy characters like ∧, ∀, and ∃ don't have codepoints in the `utf8` inputenc package, but the `utf8x` does. How do I tell emacs to pass the `utf8x` option when I generate a pdf via `org-export`?

Answer (score 1):

For example, following way:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

More examples you can find in [following file](https://raw.github.com/alexott/presentations/master/Emacs-ScalaByTalk.org)...

Comment: Gives me `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc.`

Comment: Hmmm, then I think you need to define your own export class, as described in http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html